# getJSON and mod rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mod-rewrite, getjson

I'm using the following code to retrieve values in a json fomat from my server:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/test/echo.php?jsoncallback=?",     {
        value: 'hello',
        },      function(data){
                $('#div').html(data.test);
          }); });
```

As you could see the $.getJSON url is now: http://127.0.0.1/test/echo.php?jsoncallback=?

But I prefer: **http://127.0.0.1/test/echo/**

On my server I'm using the following mod rewrite code:

> RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^test/echo/([^/.]+)
>   test/echo.php?value=$1 [L]

When I'm enter the URL (http://127.0.0.1/test/echo/hello) in my browser, everything works fine, but I'm wondering how to use the clean url in the $.getJSON request. Because for some reason the url I prefer doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query string is getting lost in your RewriteRule, try the [QSA (Query String Append) flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

```
RewriteRule ^test/echo/([^/.]+) test/echo.php?value=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That will pass the `&jsoncallback=?` part of the URL onto `test/echo.php` as well as the `value` argument